# Add class to div when with same id and display block using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to add `.active` class on `.inner-thumb-container` whenever its corresponding `.detail-box` is set to `display: block`. I have two blocks using similar code so that layout is modified on mobile and desktop views.

Here's what I have so far. Works fine until window is resized...

**jQuery:**

```
// show different div based on image map hover
jQuery("#career-img-wrap a[data-toggle]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selector = $(this).data("toggle");
    jQuery(".inner-thumb-container").removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).find(".inner-thumb-container").addClass('active');
    jQuery(".detail-box").hide();
    jQuery(".detail-box" + "#" + selector).show().addClass('animated fadeIn'); 
});
```

**HTML (written in ExpressionEngine):**

```
<div class="mobile-hide">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center thumb-container">
            {careers_benefits}
                    {careers_benefits:switch="<div class='row'>|"}
                    <div class="col-md-6" id="career-img-wrap">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="career_content_{careers_benefits:field_row_count}">
                            <div class="inner-thumb-container {if careers_benefits:field_row_count == 1}active{/if}">
                                <img src="{careers_benefits:icon}" alt="{careers_benefits:title} icon">
                                <p>{careers_benefits:title}</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    {if careers_benefits:field_row_count != careers_benefits:field_total_rows}{careers_benefits:switch="|</div>"}{/if}
                    {if careers_benefits:field_row_count == careers_benefits:field_total_rows}</div>{/if}
            {/careers_benefits} 
        </div>
        {careers_benefits}
        <div class="col-md-6 career-thumb-content detail-box" id="career_content_{careers_benefits:field_row_count}">
            <div class="career-thumb-content-inner">
                <h3>{careers_benefits:title}</h3>
                {careers_benefits:content}
            </div>
        </div>
        {/careers_benefits} 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mobile-show">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center thumb-container">
            {careers_benefits}
                <div id="career-img-wrap">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="career_content_{careers_benefits:field_row_count}">
                        <div class="inner-thumb-container">
                            <img src="{careers_benefits:icon}" alt="{careers_benefits:title} icon">
                            <p>{careers_benefits:title}</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="career-thumb-content detail-box" id="career_content_{careers_benefits:field_row_count}">
                    <div class="career-thumb-content-inner">
                        <h3>{careers_benefits:title}</h3>
                        {careers_benefits:content}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {/careers_benefits} 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mobile-hide {
    display: block;
}

.mobile-show {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 992px){
    .mobile-hide {
        display: none;
    }

    .mobile-show {
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: you should not have same id's on same page

Comment: You should get the elements by class _and_ use unique id's for each one of them.

Comment: @techLove, I don't have the same id's. Each id is incremented by 1. The data-toggle value is the same as the id. Am I missing something there?

Comment: <div class="col-md-6" id="career-img-wrap"> i see this twice

Comment: What happens when window is resized?

Comment: @doutriforce, the`detail-box` retains `display: block;`, but the `inner-thumb-container` doesn't keep the `active` class